# SPARQL: Unresolved prefixed name: dbpprop:author

Tags: java, sparql, dbpedia

I'm running this query. It works fine on DBpedia (http://dbpedia.org/sparql), but it doesn't work in my Java code:

```
PREFIX res: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?book
WHERE {
  ?book a dbpedia-owl:Book .
  ?book dbpprop:author ?author .
  ?author dbpprop:name ?name
  FILTER regex(?name, "Agatha Christie", "i")
}
```

Infact, as stated by the query validator (http://www.sparql.org/query-validator.html):

```
Line 7, column 9: Unresolved prefixed name: dbpprop:author
```

Why does it work in DBpedia then? Does DBpedia automatically add missing prefixes? Where may I found the prefix to make it work inside my Java code?

Comment: http://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl

Comment: Wow Thanks KBorja, this link will solve me a lot of problems!

Comment: If your issue is resolved, you should close the question.

Comment: @Artemis No. If the question got successfully answered, an answer should be accepted, closing is not appropriate. And if the answer was posted as a comment, consider posting it as an answer yourself.

Comment: This question has been asked more than once. Sadly no one seems to look for answers anymore and just keeps asking the same questions.

Comment: @Artemis if that is the case you should vote to close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: I agree with Artemis, but I must say wasn't in lazy mode. I performed a long search before placing the question.
Since I never solved this "prefix" issue, I asked the wrong question though. And this dbpprop author seemed so common, that was strange I couldn't find any reference.
Thank you all for your support. As for me, I'll take on trying to keep SO the useful reference it has always been.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The DBpedia endpoint by defaults knows about many of the most common prefixes for the most common vocabularies. As pointed out by KBorja in the comment above these can be looked up here: http://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl . So you want to add this to your prefixes:

```
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
```

Aside from that there also is an informal "prefix registry" that you can use to get a good guess if you encounter a prefix that you don't know the URI for: http://prefix.cc or http://prefix.cc/popular/all

Comment: also when you don't know a prefix you can substitute your unknown prefix with a variable and a filter to find out your answer:  `?author ?uri ?name` ; `FILTER (regex(?name, "Agatha Christie", "i") || ?uri =dbpprop:name)`

Comment: @ffa That code doesn't make any sense to me. To avoid using the invalid prefix `dbprop`, you use that prefix in a slightly different way?

Comment: @svick my code is meant to be run in the [dbpedia's sparql endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+res%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbpedia-owl%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+%3Furi+%3Fbook%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A++%3Fbook+a+dbpedia-owl%3ABook+.%0D%0A++%3Fbook+dbpprop%3Aauthor+%3Fauthor+.%0D%0A++%3Fauthor+%3Furi+%3Fname.%0D%0A++FILTER+%28regex%28%3Fname%2C+%22Agatha+Christie%22%2C+%22i%22%29+%7C%7C+%3Furi+%3Ddbpprop%3Aname%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: @ffa Then I think that's a very convoluted way to find what the prefix is.

Comment: Thank you and also to @KBorja.
I'm hard to get used to DBPedia, due to this prefixes paradigma. You confirm me that can easily happen you have to "guess" in some case the prefix you need.